# What am I missing about reference types in this example?

Tags: c#

I have the following code in that I create an object and pass it along through a series of forms to a user control.

```
public class MyObject
{
   public List<AnObject> Objects {get; set;}
}
```

Form 1:

```
private void MyObject _myObject = new MyObject{Objects = new List<AnObject>()};

...

Form2 form2 = new Form2(ref _myObject);
form2.Show();
```

Form 2:

```
public Form2(ref MyObject myObject)
{
    UserControl1 myControl = new UserControl1();
    myControl.Objects = myObjects.Objects
}
```

UserControl1

```
public List<AnObject> Objects {get; set;}
...

Objects.Add(new myObject());
```

When I Add a new myObject() to Objects in UserControl1, it doesn't update my original list on Form1.  I am passing myObject by reference.  The only thing I can think of that would be somehow unboxing my values is when I assign the list of AnObject to Form 2 to the UserControl1.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for us to tell what's going on. Please provide a short but complete program - ideally a console app, as I see no need to get a user interface involved here. As Henk said, you don't even need `ref` here.

Comment: Are you by any chance using myObjects as a DataSource for a Control (e.g. ListBox), and that control is not updated when adding to myObjects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **ref** has nothing with this example. Without **ref** you will pass reference of your list, just as you intended (and it would be shared by both forms). (Code where **ref** keyword is needed - is really rare code.)
2. `List<T>` has no notification about its changes. So when you change its contents in one form, the other one doesn't know about it. Consider using `ObservableCollection<T>` and subscribe to its `CollectionChanged` event in your controls.

Answer (score 2):

The `ref` shouldn't even be necessary.

> When I Add a new myObject() to Objects in UserControl1, it doesn't update my original list on Form1

It should have done that. Better post the *exact* code, this part shows me the code was not copy/pasted:

```
public Form2(ref MyObject myObject)
{
    UserControl1 myControl = new UserControl1();
    myControl.Objects = myObjects.Objects  // extra 's'
}
```

So we are now looking for a small problem in code that is an inexact copy of the real stuff. Hopeless.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in .NET are reference types anyways.  `ref` in this case is only necessary if you might want to pass a different object back out in the same parameter instead of returning a new object.  For what you're doing here, `ref` is completely unnecessary.  (Contrast this with `struct`s, which are value types, and so `ref` does something more potentially useful)  Similarly, since Objects are already value types, there is no concept of boxing or unboxing here.